# toUpperCaseFunction does not work with await keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to use an if clause like this:

```
if(await database.getValue("SDA").toUpperCase() == "AP"){
   ...
```

I got an error:

> TypeError: database.getValue(...).toUpperCase is not a
> function

However when I change the above if clause to

```
let check = await database.getValue("SDA")
if(check.toUpperCase() == "AP"){
  .....
```

It works fine.

Why does this happen in Nodejs?

Comment: What about adding parens within your `if` statement like this? `if((await database.getValue("SDA")).toUpperCase() == "AP")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Property access (`.`) has higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) (20) than `await` (17). Your current code is equivalent to:

```
if(await (database.getValue("SDA").toUpperCase()) == "AP"){
```

because the `.`s get chained together before the `await` tries to resolve the expression on the right - which doesn't work because the `getValue` call returns the Promise.

You could also fix it by grouping the `await getValue` call in parentheses:

```
if((await database.getValue("SDA")).toUpperCase() == "AP"){
```

Or by using a regular expression to get around the `==` operator precedence (see revision history, I wouldn't recommend it, it's very weird).

Personally, I'd prefer your original code of extracting it into a variable first, it's a bit more readable

Comment: I feel like your comment about the regular expression brings in an unnecessary element to this answer.  I would have preferred not to see the regular expression approach as part of the answer.  Instead, I would have preferred if you just re-explained why the "it works fine" approach of extracting to a variable first *does* work (since you prefer that.)  I acknowledge that you indirectly show that passing the awaited promise to some other function essentially forces you to enclose it in parens (or assign it to a var, as you mentioned.)

Answer (score 1):

try this shape `if((await database.getValue("SDA")).toUpperCase() == "AP"){}`
or refactor code like this

```
   try {
  const value = await database.getValue("SDA")
  if(!value) return // what you ned
  if (value === 'AP'){
    // do thomthing 
  }

} catch (e) {

// handle with error 
}
```